# iOS: Prevent Restkit from URL encoding commas

Tags: ios, objective-c, web-services, cocoa-touch, restkit

I'm using RestKit to access a web service that I do not control. In one operation, the "ageGroup" argument is required to be in the form illustrated below:

```
ag=Babies,+Toddlers,+Preschoolers,+Kids ages 6-11
```

Calling the web service from a browser using the above works fine. I also notice that my browser automatically encodes the spaces, but not the commas or plus signs.

RestKit encodes this part of the URL as:

```
ag=Babies%2C%2BToddlers%2C%2BPreschoolers%2C%2BKids%20ages%206-11
```

Trying to use this in the URL (even in a browser) does not work. I have narrowed the problem down to the commas; for whatever reason, the web service is not decoding the comma escape sequences correctly. Again, I don't have any control over the web service, so there's nothing I can do about this.

How can I prevent RestKit from encoding these commas? Is there some other workaround for this that I'm not thinking of?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

RestKit uses AFNetworking.  I believe all you have to do is modify the `AFPercentEscapedQueryStringKeyFromStringWithEncoding` function.

Remove the comma from `kAFCharactersToBeEscapedInQueryString`.

Comment: Thanks for your response! Can you give me more information about where to find this function? I see the AFNetworking folder in the RestKit project, but I don't see any reference to the function you mention.

Comment: Wait, I found it. It's in AFHTTPClient.m

Comment: Great! I'd set a breakpoint in there and step through to make sure it gives you the result you want.